# Shifting a label perpendicular to an arrow in xypic

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I have the following code depicting a commutative diagram

```
\xymatrixrowsep{40mm}\xymatrix{\mathfrak{C}(Y,Z)\times\mathfrak{C}(X,Y)\times\mathfrak{C}(W,X)\times\mathfrak{C}(V,W) \ar@/^8pc/[d] \ar@/^4pc/[d]^[@!-90]{\Gamma\circ(\Gamma\times1)\circ(\Gamma\times1\times1)} \ar[d] \ar@/_4pc/[d] \ar@/_8pc/[d] \\ \mathfrak{C}(V,Z)}
```

which yields the following image

[image]

The label in the above image is meant for the second-from-right arrow, but its extreme eccentricity causes the label to appear far off the arrow. I would like to shift the label left towards the arrow, but can't find the appropriate code -- any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC I'm not sure what you mean -- if you have xypic and xyoption{rotate} in your preamble, the above code should compile to give the above image.

Comment: Your code is not directly compilable. You have to add the packages as well as the class. Give a fully compilable code without doing anything but copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun: with `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 \mathfrak{C}(Y,Z)\times\mathfrak{C}(X,Y)\times\mathfrak{C}(W,X)\times
 \mathfrak{C}(V,W)
 \arrow[d,bend left=40,"{\Gamma\circ(\Gamma\times1)\circ(\Gamma\times1\times1)}"
 {rotate=-90,anchor=south}] 
 \arrow[d,bend left=70]
 \arrow[d,bend right=40] \arrow[d,bend right=70]  \arrow[d] \\[6em] 
 \mathfrak{C}(V,Z)
 \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are endless ways to modify this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 \mathfrak{C}(Y,Z)\times\mathfrak{C}(X,Y)\times\mathfrak{C}(W,X)\times
 \mathfrak{C}(V,W)
 \arrow[d,bend left=20,"{\Gamma\circ(\Gamma\times1)\circ(\Gamma\times1\times1)}"
 {rotate=-90,anchor=south,pos=0.4,yshift=1ex},start anchor=-14] 
 \arrow[d,bend left=50,start anchor=-7]
 \arrow[d,bend right=20,start anchor=-166] \arrow[d,bend right=50,start anchor=-173]  \arrow[d] \\[6em] 
 \mathfrak{C}(V,Z)
 \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated, it looks more and more like I should shift over to tikz.

Comment: TikZ is easiest way for most diagrams